# How to maintain only a small set of non-default kernel configs?

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I would like to be able to maintain only a small set of kernel configs and use defaults for the rest of configs.

For a minimalistic example: I would like to maintain only the config value. Like this:

```
CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE=0xdebb000000000000
```

And use this to build kernels v3.x, v4.x, and v5.x.

Because I care only about this kernel config value, it is fine for all others to be default values.

How do I do that?

Comment: diff -u default_config config >config_patch

Comment: @stark I do not understand this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the config options you want to override in a simple Bash script that exports them as environment variables before running `make`. For options that you want to *disable* (i.e. set from `y` to `n`) you will need to directly modify the `.config` file as simply exporting them as `=n` will not work.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

make defconfig

# Options you want to modify
export CONFIG_FOO=123
export CONFIG_BAR=456

# Options which you want to disable
sed -ie '/CONFIG_BAZ=y/ s/=y/=n/' .config

make all -j
```

Beware though that you should check for config dependencies (with `make menuconfig` or `make gconfig`) to see whether the config options you are dealing with also depend on others or have others as dependencies. In such case you also want to include those in your Bash script as needed.

Comment: This won't work for configs that are Y and you want to remove.

Comment: @stark thanks, updated

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using [alldefconfig/savedefconfig](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/kbuild/kconfig.html?highlight=kconfig_allconfig) targets.

Let's say, you have a minimal config called `myconfig`. Then, using command

```bash
make KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=myconfig alldefconfig
```

you expand it to full configuration `.config`, where all other options take their default values.

Now, after you've done some modifications via graphic tools, a new config version needs to be saved. You issue command

```bash
make savedefconfig
```

which removes default values from current `.config` leaving only non-default ones. New minimal configuration is saved to `defconfig` file.